# Combine two classes in Java?

Tags: java, android

I don't know what the right way to ask this but I have two classes I get back from the API that both have `name` as the thing in common but also have another field that is separate from each other. What is the best way to "combine" them where my User class can get the `name` but can also get their own variables.

How would my `User` class look? I'm looking for the `User` class to have `name` in-common, the Alien class have `alienVariable` and the Human class have the `humanVariable`

My example of two classes

Alien

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Alien implements Parcelable {
    public static Alien create(String alienVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Alien(alienVariable);
    }

    public static Alien create(String name, String alienVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Alien(name, alienVariable);
    }

    public static TypeAdapter<Alien> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_Alien.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

    @SerializedName("name")
    public abstract String name();

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("alien_variable")
    public abstract String alienVariable();
}
```

Human

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Human implements Parcelable {
    public static Human create(String humanVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Human(humanVariable);
    }

    public static Human create(String name, String humanVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Human(name, humanVariable);
    }

    public static TypeAdapter<Human> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_Human.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

    @SerializedName("name")
    public abstract String name();

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("human_variable")
    public abstract String humanVariable();
}
```

User?

Comment: Why don't you just generate POJOs using the pojo generator with each class separate?

Comment: Using method prefixes is a bad sign... You can make an abstract class with `getName` and `getVariable` methods

Answer (score 1):

use an interface with name() method in it.

Generally speaking if you have some common properties its better to have a super class rather than interfaces but if fulfill the super class slot then your only choice is interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following. BTW, I haven't tried to compile this it's just a scaffold of an idea

```
public interface Species implements Parcelable {
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name();
    @Nullable
    String typeVariable();
}

public class Alien implements Species {
    @Override
    public String name() {}

    @Override
    @SerializedName("alien_variable")
    public String alienVariable() {}

    // fill in rest of class
}

public class Human implements Species {
    @Override
    public String name(){}

    @Override
    @SerializedName("human_variable")
    public String humanVariable() {}

    // fill in rest of class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was what Vahid suggested. I didn't want inheritance but polymorphism. (should've specified)

Just made an interface class that looks like this.

```
public interface Species {
    String name();
}
```

And then just override it in each class, example for `the Human` class

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Human implements Parcelable, Species {
    public static Human create(String humanVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Human(humanVariable);
    }

    public static Human create(String name, String humanVariable) {
        return new AutoValue_Human(name, humanVariable);
    }

    public static TypeAdapter<Human> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_Human.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }

    @SerializedName("name")
    public abstract String name();

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("human_variable")
    public abstract String humanVariable();

    @Override
    public String name() {
       return name();
    }
}
```